# Complete metric space on the interval $[0,\infty)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to check if metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|+|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$ is complete on the interval $[0,\infty)$.
I know that $d(x,y)=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$ is not complete (counterexample: $x_n=n$)  but what happens when we add $|x-y|$ to it?

Comment: when you write $[0,\infty]$ is $0\in [0,\infty]$ or do you think about the open interval $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Oh sory, it should be half-opened interval, I've edited my question.

Comment: I think the question is whether $0$ is included or not.

Comment: Yes, $0$ is included

Comment: Then what is $d(0, 1)$?

Comment: I think we have to assume that $f(0)=0$, so $d(0,1)=|0-1|+|1-0|=2$

Comment: what is $d(0,x)?$

Comment: If you keep zero the metric is not well defined .. but if you keep aside zero and look at it then it is complete I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that, the set is $(0,\infty)$ instead $[0,\infty)$.
Now, if $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in this metric.
Then, $(x_n),(\frac{1}{x_n})$ both are Cauchy sequence in usual metric defined on $\bf{R}$.
So $(x_n)$ converges to some $c\ne 0$ in usual metric on $\bf{R}$ and $(\frac{1}{x_n})$ also converges to $(\frac{1}{c})$
Thus, in this metric $d$ $(x_n)$ converges to  $c\ne 0$.
So, $((0,\infty),d)$ is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the metric is defined as
$$
 d(0, 0) = 0 \, ,\\
 d(0, x) = d(x, 0) = x + \frac 1x \text{ for } x > 0 \, ,\\
 d(x, y) = |x-y| + \left|\frac 1x -\frac 1y \right | \text{ for } x, y > 0 \, .
$$

Now let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d$. Since $d(0, x) \ge 2$ there are only two possible cases:

- All but finitely many $x_n$ are zero. In that case $d(x_n, 0) \to 0$ and we are done.
- All but finitely many $x_n$ are non-zero. Without loss of generality we can assume that *all* $x_n \ne 0$.

In the second case, both $(x_n)$ and $(1/x_n)$ are Cauchy sequences with respect to the Euclidean metric, and therefore convergent in that metric. If the respective limit values are $a$ and $b$ then $ab=1$, so that both are non-zero.

Then
$$
 d(x_n, a) = |x_n - a | + \left|\frac 1{x_n} - b\right| \to 0
$$
so that $(x_n)$ is convergent with respect to the metric $d$.

Answer (score 0):

$d'(x,y)=|x-y|$ is already a complete metric on $[0,\infty)$, being a closed subset of the complete $(\Bbb R, d')$. Why do you want another ill-defined (at $0$) one?

Answer (score 0):

If at all you want to bring $0$ into the picture you should define the metric like the this:
$$d(0, 0) = 0 \, ,\\
 d(0, x) = d(x, 0) = x + \frac 1x \text{ for } x > 0 \, ,\\
 d(x, y) = |x-y| + \left|\frac 1x -\frac 1y \right | \text{ for } x, y > 0 \, .$$
*Before we proceed just verify it gives you a metric on* $[0,\infty)$ .

- Now observe that $0$ is an isolated point in the given metric space $([0,\infty),d)$.

(Why?)
Since $d(x,0)\ge 2, \forall x \in (0,\infty)$ .

- Also observe that there can't be any Cauchy sequence which has infinitely many Zero and infinitely many non-zero terms in it.

(Why?)
Again the same reason $d(x,0)\ge 2, \forall x \in (0,\infty)$ .

If ${x_n}$ is a Cauchy-sequence then it(our discussion) leaves us with two possibilities:

1. **The Cauchy sequence all but finitely many terms zero.**
    $\implies$ the sequence converges to $0$ (trivial)
2. **The Cauchy sequence all but finitely many terms non-zero.**
   As you already know you should be bothered about the tail of the sequence, so you can ignore the finitely many zeros of the sequence. Then just observe just observe that 
   $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$$\implies |x_n-x_m|<\epsilon \text{ and } \left|\frac{1}{x_n} -\frac {1}{x_m} \right | <\epsilon $ Then you can say that ${x_n}$ converges in $([0,\infty),d)$ .

Hence you can say that $([0,\infty),d)$ is complete!

If you have read this far Thanks!